# Speed up SQL nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called `ntr_perf` with the following column: `data`, `cos`, `network`, `tot_reg`, `tot_rej`.
I need to get the sums of `tot_reg` and `tot_rej` for each pair data-cos (I need to take all data-cos pairs and make the sum of the values for all the networks with the same data-cos pair).

I'm using the following `MySQL` query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    data AS d, 
    cos AS c, 
    (SELECT SUM(tot_reg) FROM ntr_perf WHERE data=d AND cos=c) AS sumattempts, 
    (SELECT SUM(tot_rej) FROM ntr_perf WHERE data=d AND cos=c) AS sumrej FROM ntr_perf
```

It takes a very long time even if the table has only 91.450 rows (the table has a multi-column index data-cos).

Is it possible to speed up the query?

Comment: Can you say what is data=d and cos=c?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is exactly what group by is designed for.

Try this:

```
SELECT data,cos,SUM(tot_reg),SUM(tot_rej) from ntr_perf group by data,cos
```

Comment: the where xondition is missing.

Comment: There are `WHERE` conditions in `SUM` subqueries, so this query will return false result.

Comment: @Nebi & Tedo But in question this is what he explained. Those where clause are just filtered with alias name from select

Comment: My script reacted to this task "I need to take all data-cos pairs and make the sum of the values for all the networks with the same data-cos pair"

Comment: Some millisecond instead of some minutes, GROUP BY is actually what I needed but I didn't know its meaning. Thanks to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this query,

```
SELECT data AS d, cos AS c,
SUM(tot_reg), SUM(tot_reg) where 
data='d' AND cos='c' group by data , cos ;
```

Hope you got is. Else let me know, will help you

Answer (score 0):

Try this, a group by

```
SELECT data d,
       cos c,
       SUM(tot_reg) sumattempts,
       SUM(tot_rej) sumrej
FROM ntr_perf 
WHERE data = 'd'  -- if these are values, put in single quotes
AND cos = 'c' -- if these are values, put in single quotes
GROUP BY data, -- even though aliased, the original name needs to be used on the GROUP BY
         cos -- even though aliased, the original name needs to be used on the GROUP BY
```

Answer (score 0):

this will group your query and filter your sums, as you posted `WHERE` conditions:

```
SELECT 
    data AS d, 
    cos AS c,
    SUM(IIF(data='d' AND cos='c', tot_reg, 0) AS sumattempts,
    SUM(IIF(data='d' AND cos='c', tot_rej, 0)) AS sumrej 
FROM 
    ntr_perf 
GROUP BY 
    data,
    cos
```